# Safari does not render SVG image correctly

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

```
<p class="flex align_center"><span class="has_bg_img setting_coin_span" id="setting_coin_span_header"></span> 0</p>

.setting_coin_span {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-image: url(images/coin_ico2.svg);
}
```

I have an example element as above in my React project. I apply svg background-image with css to the span tag inside the p tag, it works perfectly in chrome and edge browsers. but when I try in safari, the svg renders incorrectly, and the photo does not display correctly

[image: chrome]

[image: safari]

You can see it in the sample photos below. In chrome, it works in both the above and below element, but in safari it doesn't appear completely above, but below displays incorrectly.

here my svg file :

```
<svg width="34" height="34" viewBox="0 0 34 34" fill="none"  mimeType="image/svg+xml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g filter="url(#filter0_b)">
<path d="M17 34C26.3891 34 34 26.3891 34 17C34 7.6109 26.3891 0 17 0C7.6109 0 0 7.6109 0 17C0 26.3891 7.6109 34 17 34ZM17 9.7869L24.2131 17L17 24.2131L9.7869 17L17 9.7869Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
</g>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0.366337 17.3661H10.2373V16.4521H0.366337V17.3661Z" fill="url(#paint1_linear)"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M16.6339 0.366825L16.6339 10.2378L17.5479 10.2378L17.5479 0.366825L16.6339 0.366825Z" fill="url(#paint2_linear)"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M17.5487 33.6332L17.5487 23.7622L16.6348 23.7622L16.6348 33.6332L17.5487 33.6332Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M33.6337 16.4513L23.7627 16.4513L23.7627 17.3652L33.6337 17.3652L33.6337 16.4513Z" fill="url(#paint4_linear)"/>
<defs>
<filter id="filter0_b" x="-10" y="-10" width="54" height="54" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feGaussianBlur in="BackgroundImage" stdDeviation="5"/>
<feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="effect1_backgroundBlur"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_backgroundBlur" result="shape"/>
</filter>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="19.8899" y1="-9.0353" x2="18.622" y2="34.5971" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0.234375" stop-color="#7D54F2"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#702BE1"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint1_linear" x1="10.2373" y1="17.3661" x2="0.366337" y2="17.3661" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#9163F2"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#A478FF" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint2_linear" x1="16.6339" y1="10.2378" x2="16.6339" y2="0.366825" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#9163F2"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#A478FF" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint3_linear" x1="17.5487" y1="23.7622" x2="17.5487" y2="33.6332" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#9163F2"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#A478FF" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint4_linear" x1="23.7627" y1="16.4513" x2="33.6337" y2="16.4513" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#9163F2"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#A478FF" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
```

What do you think is the problem?

Comment: Thanks. I don't know whether this is the full problem, but caniuse reports feFlood and feBlend as 'status unknown' in Safari and I see on an iPad that that cross-type figure is rendered rather than a filled-in icon such as I see on Edge/Windows10 so it seems likely that one or other or both properties aren't fully supported on Safari. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69820782/safari-does-not-render-svg-image-correctly#69820782

Comment: Oh, I was going to make a live snippet for you, but on my Safari 15.1 on Monterey it works exactly as on Chrome and Firefox: https://jsfiddle.net/65r3wvpg/ Can you confirm you do see the problem in this fiddle and add details about your browser's version?

Comment: When I open the jsfiddle link in mac chrome, it renders correctly, but when I open it in safari, it is incorrect.

Comment: and my mac safari version is : Version 14.1 (16611.1.21.161.6)

Comment: ... So they probably fixed it in the latest version. Are you still on BigSur? You can't update Safari to v15 from there right?

Answer (score 0):

Probably an issue related to some particular Safari versions.
However there are some irregularities in your svg sode that might enhance compatibility:

filter **"filter0_b"** doesn't seem to work. Maybe it's preventing your background circle from rendering.

```
<filter id="filter0_b" x="-10" y="-10" width="54" height="54" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
    <feGaussianBlur in="BackgroundImage" stdDeviation="5"/>
    <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="effect1_backgroundBlur"/>
    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_backgroundBlur" result="shape"/>
</filter>
```

Besides the fill rules `fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"` are not needed (changing anything)

```svg
<svg width="34" height="34" viewBox="0 0 34 34"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
<defs>
<!--
<filter id="filter0_b" x="-10" y="-10" width="54" height="54" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
    <feGaussianBlur in="BackgroundImage" stdDeviation="5"/>
    <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="effect1_backgroundBlur"/>
    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_backgroundBlur" result="shape"/>
</filter>
-->
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="19.8899" y1="-9.0353" x2="18.622" y2="34.5971" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0.234375" stop-color="#7D54F2"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#702BE1"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint1_linear" x1="10.2373" y1="17.3661" x2="0.366337" y2="17.3661" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#9163F2"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#A478FF" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint2_linear" x1="16.6339" y1="10.2378" x2="16.6339" y2="0.366825" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#9163F2"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#A478FF" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint3_linear" x1="17.5487" y1="23.7622" x2="17.5487" y2="33.6332" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#9163F2"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#A478FF" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint4_linear" x1="23.7627" y1="16.4513" x2="33.6337" y2="16.4513" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#9163F2"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#A478FF" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>

<path id="bg-circle" d="M17 34C26.3891 34 34 26.3891 34 17C34 7.6109 26.3891 0 17 0C7.6109 0 0 7.6109 0 17C0 26.3891 7.6109 34 17 34ZM17 9.7869L24.2131 17L17 24.2131L9.7869 17L17 9.7869Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
<path d="M0.366337 17.3661H10.2373V16.4521H0.366337V17.3661Z" fill="url(#paint1_linear)"/>
<path d="M16.6339 0.366825L16.6339 10.2378L17.5479 10.2378L17.5479 0.366825L16.6339 0.366825Z" fill="url(#paint2_linear)"/>
<path d="M17.5487 33.6332L17.5487 23.7622L16.6348 23.7622L16.6348 33.6332L17.5487 33.6332Z" fill="url(#paint3_linear)"/>
<path d="M33.6337 16.4513L23.7627 16.4513L23.7627 17.3652L33.6337 17.3652L33.6337 16.4513Z" fill="url(#paint4_linear)"/>

</svg>
```

Some browser are less tolerant. Especially filters can cause errors or different rendering behaviours.

Whenever you experience the issue of elements not being rendered, try to deactivate filters. If an element 'reappears' after diabling the filter, you can check this filter's defs.